# Is it legal to obtain the global IP address and get the country within an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ip, country

I just heard about this. I am planning to develop an ios application- iPhone and iPad versions. The app needs to show content based on the country where its accessed from. (note I only need the country and not any more further details).

Can I obtain the current global IP address of the iPhone/iPad and then convert it to country based on a database that I have myself in a server ?

Is it legal to do this as I just heard that it violates apple's policies ?

I don't want to go for location services to handle this, as I feel its much easier for me to obtain the country using the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

That is legal and already in practice by several applications. Not really fail-safe (easy to spoof, VPN connections, etc).

EDIT: 'That is legal' is based on the next statement 'Already in practice'. Some big corporations use it, so I assumed it is a legal action. I am not an expert on legal matters, however.

Answer (score 1):

you could find the country using this

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSString *countryName = [locale displayNameForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode value: countryCode]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the user's locale is probably the best option, but if you want to use the IP address, then there is a free database [here](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry). That page also has free libraries for searching the database with an IP address.

If you're doing everything on the server, then it is completely legal, and not against any Apple rules.